# In spark1.6 Java API how to get all partition values of a dataframe?

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe which is partitioned on 3 columns, I would like to know  If there is a way to get the unique values of those partitions with the partition names without iterating over the whole dataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

I had looked a bit into spark(1.6 and also 2.4) source code without finding a viable way. 
Usually to retrieve data about partitions you convert your Dataframe into an rdd. You will then get a MapPartitionsRDD and you can use methods such as:

- getNumPartitions
- partitioner (return the partitioner. Converting to rdd blows the information so use DF.queryExecution.toRdd.partitioner.getOrElse(null) )
- glom (Return an RDD created by coalescing all elements within each partition
      into a list)

None of which seems to answer your question. You can also do something like:

```
someDF.repartition(1).rdd.partitions
```

To get an Array[Partition]. However, from a partition you can get only the index of that partition inside the rdd.